# Static types cannot be used as parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I'm following the MVC Music Store tutorial, but I've just gotten a bit stuck with the Html Helper in part 5: [Part 5](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-5).

I seem to have followed it correctly so far (please correct me if I'm wrong :) )...however I am getting the following error:

> 'musicStoreMVC.Helpers.HtmlHelper':
>   static types cannot be used as
>   parameters

Here is the code from my application:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace musicStoreMVC.Helpers
{
    public static class HtmlHelper
    {
        public static string Truncate(this HtmlHelper helper, string input, int length)
        {
            if (input.Length <= length)
            {
                return input;
            }
            else
            {
                return input.Substring(0, length) + "...";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone can see what I'm doing wrong, or if more info is needed, I'd be grateful for the pointers!! Thanks.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who answered! Names were just too similar!! :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858591/c-sharp-static-types-cannot-be-used-as-type-arguments

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just rename your static `HtmlHelper` class to `HtmlHelperExtensions`.

Comment: Same problem but is not working for me. I want to extend `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Assert`. Changing the class name to anything also produce the same error...

Comment: Got it, because extension methods cannot be added to `static class` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249222/can-i-add-extension-methods-to-an-existing-static-class

Answer (score 1):

You got a name conflict - the one static `HtmlHelper` that you declare in the example code and the `System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper` which is the class that you actually want to create the extension method for. Just rename your class to `HtmlHelpers` (as it is in the linked tutorial). The way it is right now, you are trying to implement an extension method on the static class which supposedly does not work.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're naming your extension class HtmlHelper. In `truncate`, you then try to add a extension method to a static class, which you cannot.

A simple solution is to rename your `HtmlHelper` to something different.

Answer (score 1):

The `this HtmlHelper helper` says that `Truncate()` should act as if it were an instance method on `HtmlHelper`, but you've declared `HtmlHelper` as a static class, which can't have instances.

If what you're trying to do is create an extension method on a different `HtmlHelper` class, then as others have suggested, rename this static class. If you just need the static method, get rid of the `this HtmlHelper helper` parameter. You're not using it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the using part

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Web;
```

and add

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
```