# C# - static types cannot be used as type arguments

Tags: c#, generics, static

I've a generic class that helps me to do checks on argument values:

```
internal sealed class Argument<T>
    where T : class
{
    private void TraceAndThrow(Exception ex)
    {
        new InternalTraceHelper<T>().WriteError(ex);
        throw ex;
    }

    internal void ThrowNull(object value, string argName)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(value, null))
        {
            TraceAndThrow(new ArgumentNullException(argName));
        }
    }

    internal void ThrowIf(bool condition, string argName)
    {
        if (condition)
        {
            TraceAndThrow(new ArgumentException(null, argName));
        }
    }


    internal void ThrowNotInEnum(Type enumType, object value)
    {
        if (!Enum.IsDefined(enumType, value))
        {
            TraceAndThrow(new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(Resources.ArgEnumIllegalVal.InvariantFormat(value)));
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try to use it with a static class:

```
internal static class Class1
{
    private static Argument<Class1> _arg;
}
```

I got this error (at compilation):

> static types cannot be used as type arguments

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This is deliberate.

Static classes try to prevent inappropriate use, so in almost all situations, you can't use them in situations where you'd normally want an *instance* of the type... and that includes type arguments.

See section ["Static classes" of the C# 6 spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#14224-static-classes) for the very limited set of situations in which you can refer to static class types.

Comment: Doing my static classes non static but with a private constructor will do the job? So no one can instanciate it, but is non-static. Is this a good way to perform it? (Thanks for the section, I've read it)

Comment: @Arnaud F.: Well that would *work* - but what are you using the type argument for? What's the point of it? It looks like it's only used by `InternalTraceHelper`, and we don't know what that's like.

Comment: `InternalTraceHelper` does `Trace.Write()`, the argument type is used to define the category of the trace. Can be replaced by `Trace.WriteLine("a message", typeof(T).FullName); // Where T = Class1`

Comment: @Arnaud F.: It sounds like you possibly want a non-generic version of InternalTraceHelper which takes a `Type` instead. In fact, you could make the whole class non-generic, just with a generic method to make creation simpler: `InternalTraceHelper.Create<Foo>` would call `new InternalTraceHelper(typeof(T))` where `T` is the type parameter for the method.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip Master !

Answer (score 5):

Generics only work with instances, not static classes.

Comment: Is there a workaround? How can I manage it? I wouldn't check "manually" in static classes and using `Argument<T>` in the non-static one...

Comment: No there isn't other than using `System.Type`.

Comment: @Arnaud, you can't pass static types as arguments, so I fail to see when you'd ever want to have an `Argument<StaticType>`, unless I'm being misled by your class name.

Comment: Doing my static classes non static but with a private constructor will do the job? So no one can instanciate it, but is non-static. Is this a good way to perform it?

Comment: yeah this is definitely an informative answer. why did u bother to write such a long text ?

Answer (score 2):

Since static classes cannot be instantiated, it can never create `Argument<T>` with a static type.

Comment: That is incorrect.  ILogger<T> is an example where the class becomes a category for the logger to use when emitting diagnostics.  This is a stupid rule.

Comment: @Quarkly, did you find a way around it? considering just making the class non-static now

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing wrong is using a static type as a generic type argument.

Answer (score 0):

Since static classes won't have instance members, my concern would be what kind of thing I'm going to do with them.

I believe that, missing that you can't use static classes as generic arguments, I believe that you need to do this with extension methods instead of a generic class.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods