# Passing Type variable as Generic Type Parameter to Static Class

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have the following static class

```
public static class MyFoo<T> where T : class
{
    public static IBar<T> Begin()
    {
        return new Bar<T>();
    }
}
```

Elsewhere, I have a variable of System.Type, which I need to pass in as the Generic Type argument, ideally:

```
public void MyFunction(Type type)
{
     MyFoo<type>.Begin();
}
```

I know its possible through reflection to return an instance of MyFoo (If i make it non static) but this would not be ideal. Is there anyway to pass type as a Generic Type argument to the MyFoo static class?

Comment: First of all if you make it non-static you don't need reflection, you can enforce a parameterless constructor with a generic constraint on `T`.  Second, what problem are you trying to solve here? Why isn't T a parameter of MyFunction (it can be inferred for you)

Comment: see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858591/c-sharp-static-types-cannot-be-used-as-type-arguments

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. @BenjaminGruenbaum unfortunately I can't divulge too much but it would of been in my best interests if this was possible, to save myself a lot of time form something i've inherited. I shall un-static the situation! Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't do it. The value of the `type` variable in the second sample is only known at *run time*. The `T` type parameter in the first sample **must** be resolved at *compile time*.

Instead, look into [`Activator.CreateInstance()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, I'll craft a workaround from a non static version :)