# Has extending static classes using extension methods been made possible in .NET 4.0+?

Tags: c#-4.0, .net-4.0, extension-methods, .net-4.5

I have read that it is possible to extend static classes in F#, though it was not yet possible in C#. Multiple workarounds are proposed and therefore suggesting that this type of extension could be reasonably useful.

Though the extension methods are defined as static, they work on type instances being extended.

Because nothing allows me to think it is now available, I was wondering whether such feature is now made doable to extend a static class using the extension methods syntax in C# in .NET 4.0+?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I add extension methods to an existing static class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249222/can-i-add-extension-methods-to-an-existing-static-class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Augmenting static classes with extension methods probably won't be possible in C# in the reasonable future, unless the language changes the way extension methods are declared.

Imagine we have to add this feature to the language. Extension methods are currently defined as static methods taking an additional parameter decorated with the `this` keyword:

```
public class Foo
{
}

public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static void ExtendFoo(this Foo foo, string bar)
    {
    }
}
```

In the code above, the `this` decorator is the only thing that instructs the compiler to treat `ExtendFoo()` as an extension method that augments class `Foo`. In other words, we cannot get rid of parameter `foo`, which will refer to the *instance of `Foo`* to which the extension method will apply, i.e. the equivalent of `this` if the method was native to `Foo`. Problem is, static classes cannot be instantiated, so what are we going to pass in that parameter?

We can handwave the problem away and enact that if `Foo` is static, then the compiler should emit code that passes `null` instead of an actual instance of `Foo` (that cannot exist anyway). But that would be an obvious kludge, and probably shouldn't be part of the language for this reason only. Expect `NullReferenceExceptions` all over the place otherwise.

Comment: +1 This is indeed a good explanation. Aside, I cannot think of a particular way to make it possible, though there might or might not be a way to implement such feature. Perhaps by simply putting a 'static' keyword before 'this' or before the type itself only would suffice, though I can't say anything regarding the impacts that it may have to make it this way. Thanks for your time! =)