# How can I compare doubles using a specified tolerance in NUnit?

Tags: c#, nunit

I am currently developing a C# P/invoke wrapper to a DLL that is part of my product. I have no experience with C# and this is the first significant C# coding I have done. I am acutely aware that I am lacking a lot of knowledge of the finer points and idioms of the language.

My question concerns the unit tests that I am writing for which I am using NUnit. I have a need to compare the values of `double[]` variables. If I use `Assert.AreEqual(...)` to do this then the values are compared for exact equality. However, I would like to compare up to a tolerance. There are `AreEqual()` overloads for scalar real values that admit a `delta` parameter. However, I have not been able to find an equivalent for arrays. Have I missed something obvious?

At the moment I have solved the problem with the following code:

```
class Assert : NUnit.Framework.Assert
{
    public static void AreEqual(double[] expected, double[] actual, double delta)
    {
        AreEqual(expected.Length, actual.Length);
        for (int i = 0; i < expected.Length; i++)
        {
            AreEqual(expected[i], actual[i], delta);
        }
    }
}
```

Whilst this appears to work I wonder if there is a cleaner solution available. In particular I am concerned that using the same name for my derived class is, not only poor style, but could lead to un-anticipated problems down the road.

I would have like to use extension methods but I understand they are only viable for when there is an instance of the class under extension. Of course, I only ever call static methods on the `Assert` class.

I'm sorry if this seems a bit nebulous, but my instincts tell me that I'm not doing this the best way and I would like to know how to do it right.

Comment: Did you try [Extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)?

Comment: @Ofer Zelig while i gave you the +1 i remembered that Extension Methods, while defined static, only work on instances.

Comment: So as it seems now, that can't be done (unless you're implementing wrapper class, lots of hard and ugly work). See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249222/can-i-add-extension-methods-to-an-existing-static-class/435617#435617) and [this](http://madprops.org/blog/static-extension-methods/).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since the introduction of the fluent assertion syntax in NUnit, the `Within()` method has been available for this purpose:

```
double actualValue = 1.989;
double expectedValue = 1.9890;
Assert.That(actualValue, Is.EqualTo(expectedValue).Within(0.00001));
Assert.That(actualValue, Is.EqualTo(expectedValue).Within(1).Ulps);
Assert.That(actualValue, Is.EqualTo(expectedValue).Within(0.1).Percent);
```

For collections, the default behaviour of `Is.EqualTo()` is to compare the collections' members individually, with these individual comparisons being modified by `Within()`. Hence, you can compare two arrays of doubles like so:

```
var actualDoubles = new double[] {1.0 / 3.0, 0.7, 9.981};
var expectedDoubles = new double[] { 1.1 / 3.3, 0.7, 9.9810};
Assert.That(actualDoubles, Is.EqualTo(expectedDoubles).Within(0.00001));
Assert.That(actualDoubles, Is.EqualTo(expectedDoubles).Within(1).Ulps);
Assert.That(actualDoubles, Is.EqualTo(expectedDoubles).Within(0.1).Percent);
```

This will compare each element of `actualDoubles` to the corresponding element in `expectedDoubles` using the specified tolerance, and will fail if any are not sufficiently close.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. It looks like it's the way I am expected to solve the problem. I appreciate your time here. Thank you so much. As a matter of personal taste, I find these fluent interfaces a bit opaque. Once you've written it down, it kind of makes sense, but you have to crack the code in order to write it the first time!

Comment: I think the trick with fluent interfaces of this sort is 'dot-driven development'. If you're using an IDE like Visual Studio, you only need to know the first 'link in the chain', e.g. `Is`, then you can hit `.` and Intellisense will show you all the options for your 'next step'. I learned about many features like `Within()` that way, rather than by reading the NUnit docs.

Comment: Imo the 'trick' with fluent interfaces is that you have to keep in mind that it isn't supposed to make sense or be readable, it's primarily supposed to look cool. I can't think of any other explanation for the introduction of abominations like 'Assert.That(actual, Is.Not.Null.And.Not.Empty)'. I can't imagine anyone would have the audacity to claim that a 6 element deep object graph to perform a simple comparision is better by any objective measure than the Assert.IsNotNullOrEmpty which seemed to work perfectly well for 40 years without anyone complaining.

Answer (score 4):

I had a need to create custom assert, in your case there was an alternative provided by the framework. However this didn't work when I wanted to have a completely custom assert. I solved this by adding a new static class calling into nunit.

```
public static class FooAssert
{
     public static void CountEquals(int expected, FooConsumer consumer)
     {
         int actualCount = 0;
         while (consumer.ConsumeItem() != null)
             actualCount++;

         NUnit.Framework.Assert.AreEqual(expected, actualCount);
     }
}
```

Then in a test

```
[Test]
public void BarTest()
{
    // Arrange
    ... 

    // Act
    ...

    // Assert
    FooAssert.CountEquals(1, fooConsumer);
}
```

<sub>I know I am a little bit late for the party, it might still be useful for somebody</sub>

Answer (score 2):

I think what I would have done is simply define a function somewhere in your test harness

`public static bool AreEqual( double[], double[], double delta )`

that does the comparison and returns true or false appropriately.  In your Test you simply write :

```
Assert.IsTrue( AreEqual( expected, result, delta ) ) ;
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It's certainly a good idea. The downside for me is that I found that when I tried to implement this I had to reimplement the `delta` comparison that comes for free when you call AreEqual with real scalar inputs. So the answer of @dowhilefor seemed to fit my needs better this time. Thanks for caring!

Answer (score 2):

"Better" is always a matter of taste. In this case, i would say yes. You should make your own assert, without subclassing the nunit assert. Nunit already has multiple Assert classes with different specific assertions. Like [CollectionAssert](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=collectionAssert&r=2.5.9). Otherwise your method is fine.

Comment: Thanks for this. I hadn't spotted the other `XXXAssert` classes. So I added an `ArrayAssert` class and moved my code in there. It feels quite natural now and my bad vibes have receded.