# extend the colorclass in c# with a static method

Tags: c#, class, colors, extension-methods

I try to add a method to the color class in C#

```
public static class ColorExtensions 
{
    public static System.Drawing.Color GrayTone(int Darkness)
    {
        return Color.FromArgb(255 - Darkness, 255 - Darkness, 255 - Darkness);
    }
}
```

But I cannot use it like

```
Color MyColor = Color.GrayTone(80);
```

Using

```
public static class ColorExtensions 
{
    public static Color MakeBlack(this Color color)
    {
        return Color.Black;
    }
}
Color Test = Color.Beige.MakeBlack();
```

works. How can I add the method GrayTone to the color class? I read [Can I add extension methods to an existing static class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249222/can-i-add-extension-methods-to-an-existing-static-class) but unfortunately I cannot translate it into my Situation.

Comment: Have you read the *accepted* answer? (`No. Extension methods require an instance of an object.`) like `Color.Beige`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an extension method, so you need to specify the type name:

```
Color MyColor = ColorExtensions.GrayTone(80);
```

In order to make an extension method, you would need to provide an instance of `Color`, which requires an *instance*, not just the class name.  There is no way to add a static method to an existing class.