# How to add a new static method to existed Class?

Tags: c#, class, static-members

I've searched and read MSDN, but I only found out [how to add a instance method to a existed class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.ASPX).

Now, I want to add a static method to an existing class, like this:

```
String.myStaticMethod(....);
```

Can I do this? Is this not allowed in c#?

Comment: I think `C#` won't never support such a strange requirement, if you want some static methods **for your current project** or even for your own library, just define a static class for it, even you can name it the same to some existing class but note about namespace.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I add extension methods to an existing static class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249222/can-i-add-extension-methods-to-an-existing-static-class)

Comment: thanks a lot. I mean not only in static class case in this problem.
maybe it's not a static class which included some static method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Extension methods only work for instance methods at this time, not static.  There is no way to simulate adding static methods to an existing type defined in another assembly at this time in C#