# C# extensions method

Tags: c#, class

For such an extension:

```
public static class ImageExtensions
{
    public static Image LoadImage(string path)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(path)))
            return Image.FromStream(ms);
    }
}
```

How to make it possible to be called `Image.LoadImage(path)` instead of `ImageExtensions.LoadImage(path)`?

I can normally use other extension methods, where their first parameter is `this Image img`. Those work by using `instance.Method()`.

Comment: similar question with some more detailed answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249222/can-i-add-extension-methods-to-an-existing-static-class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible. You cannot write extension methods that act as static extensions, because extensions methods require an object instance.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, a method with signature `public static Image LoadImage(string path` isn't even an extension.  It is just a static method, therefore to write this as you would like it simply change the class name:

```
public static class Image
{
    public static Image LoadImage(string path)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(path)))
            return Image.FromStream(ms);
    }
}
```