# Define new extension method in class Queryable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm using mvc 5 and wanna define extension method `FindMessageAsync` in class `Queryable` (namespace System.Linq).

I usually use this way to get some records in database:

```
public void GetMessage(string id)
{
  using (var db = new MyDbContext())
  {    
    var message = db.Message.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
    //or
    var _message = db.Message.Where(x => x.Id == id).ToList();

    //do stuff
  }
}
```

I wanna improve the method to:

```
public async Task<MessageViewModels> GetMessage(string id)
{
  using (var db = new MyDbContext())
  {    
    var message = await db.Message.FindMessageAsync(x => x.Id == id);

    if (message != null)
    {
      //string id = message.Id;
      //string fromUser = message.FromUser;
      //string toUser = message.ToUser;
      //string content = message.Content;
      //bool isRead = message.IsRead;
    }

    //do stuff
  }
}
```

My question is: How to define extension method `FindMessageAsync`?

**UPDATE:**

The answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249222/can-i-add-extension-methods-to-an-existing-static-class) don't solve my problem.

Comment: Do you think this should be an `IQueryable` extension method? Seems to me that it is very specific to your domain model.

Comment: @DannyChen Please re-open my question. It's not duplicate.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov ya. Class `Queryable` contains `IQueryable` extension method.

Comment: @HappyCoding Your questions are not exactly the same, but the answers (not only the acccepted answer) in the link  answer yours.

Comment: @HappyCoding If you just want a simple extension method for `IQueryable`, see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx). The location of the extension method doesn't matter, you don't have to put it in `Queryable` class.

Comment: @DannyChen Do you see lambda expression in the extension method? I wanna use it as a parameter what all the answers of that question didn't talk about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a single item, `.FirstOrDefault` (as well as related methods like `First` `Single`) is the best choice, it's really unnecessary to implement another extension method and wrap it.

If you want a list asynchronously, probably you want [`.ToListAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.tolistasync(v=vs.113).aspx) method.

Comment: Yup. `await db.Message.Where(x => x.Id == id).ToListAsync()` = `await db.Message.FindMessageAsync(x => x.Id == id)`

Answer (score 1):

```
public static class MyQueryableExtensions {
    public static Task<T> FindMessageAsync<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) {
        if(source == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        }
        // Or whatever...
        return source.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
    }
}
```

The important things are that your method is defined within a `static` class, that your method is declared `static` and that the first parameter has the `this` modifier. It does not matter where exactly the method lives, as long as it's a static class. It doesn't need to be `System.Linq.Queryable`.

However, you should think twice as to whether you really want to implement domain-specific logic in extension methods...

Comment: Possible `T` is `MessageViewModels` :)

Comment: @HappyCoding that can be infered from the usage of the method ;) However, as @Danny Chen said, it's not really necessary to provide a wrapper around `FirstOrDefault`. It **might** make sense to provide additional logic here (while, as I said, there might be better places for that than extension methods). What is your exact use case?