# Unity extend SceneManager class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I try extend SceneManager class.

I write like [here](https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/extension-methods):

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static void LoadSceneWithSave(this SceneManager SceneManager) {
            Debug.Log("Debug LoadSceneWithSave");
    }
}
```

But when I try to use this new method:

```cs
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;
    using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

    public class SomeClass : MonoBehaviour 

    {

    void Start () {
        SceneManager.LoadSceneWithSave();
    }

}
```

It doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I add extension methods to an existing static class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249222/can-i-add-extension-methods-to-an-existing-static-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, you can. Although, you will need to explicitly create instance of `SceneManager` class before you can use that new function(`LoadSceneWithSave`). An extension method requires an instance of the class to work.

*This should work*:

```
SceneManager mySeneManager = new SceneManager();
mySeneManager.LoadSceneWithSave();
```

**How does the `transform` example you [linked](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/extension-methods) work without an instance?**

*It does have an instance*. The reason why you need to create an instance of it and can't directly use it like you can with the `Transform` class:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static void ResetTransformation(this Transform trans)
    {
    }
}
```

**...**

```
public class SomeClass : MonoBehaviour 
{
    void Start () {
        transform.ResetTransformation();
    }
}
```

is because `SceneManager` is not declared in `MonoBehaviour` or any base class of `MonoBehaviour`. There is an instance of `Transform` class named `transform` that is declared in the `Component` class which `Behaviour` inherits from which `MonoBehaviour` inherits from.

**Here is exactly what it looks like**:

```
public class Object
{

}

public class Component : Object
{
    public Transform transform { get; } //This is declared
    //...Other variables
}

public class Behaviour : Component
{

}

public class MonoBehaviour : Behaviour
{

}
```

Finally, this is why you can use the `transform` variable to access its extension method like:

```
public class SomeClass : MonoBehaviour 
{
    void Start () {
        transform.ResetTransformation();
    }
}
```

because it was already declared and you inherited it from `MonoBehaviour` .

As you can see, `SceneManager` is not declared any where in the `MonoBehaviour` class or it's base classes and you need an instance of it to access any of its extension function.