# Add custom method to Console - C#

Tags: c#, function, methods

I want to create a custom method that will work when added after “Console” in c#. It would be sort of similar to `Console.WriteLine()`.

It would look something like this: `Console.PrintMyName()`. And when it is called, it would do this: `Console.WriteLine(“James”)`.

Is there some way to do this by defining a function that only works as a method when put after after “Console”.

Comment: Have a look at this [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249222/can-i-add-extension-methods-to-an-existing-static-class) post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, no.

The closest thing you can do is approximate what you want.

The Console class (`System.Console` specifically) is a static class and so cannot have "methods added to it" in the same way as a class that can be instantiated (instantiated classes can have [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)).

The closest you can come to this is to either

- create your own class named `Console` with it's own `PrintMyName` method. However, if you use both `System.Console` and your custom `MyCustom.Console` in the same compilation unit, you will have to disambiguate them by addressing one or both by their full namespace.
- create a new static class with a completely different name.

Comment: Thanks for the info. How would I add a method to a non static class? For example how can I add a method to a WinForms control like: tabControl1.myCustomMethod()