C# kind of extension method for static function
With extension method, it is possible to add function that you call an instance.
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static bool MyNewExtension(this String s)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
...
string s = "";
s.MyNewExtension();

I don't think it is possible to add a static method extension like this?
String.MyNewExtension(s)

It is most likely a dummy idea.
My use case is that in .NET 8 some static methods were added and I am in .NET 6 ; so I would like to create those static methods to be able to write the same code as in .NET 8 but without doing the whole migration.

Thanks for the link to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249222/can-i-add-extension-methods-to-an-existing-static-class
My question has been closed for duplicate, but my question is for "non static classic" to get kind of "static extension for method"
The duplicate linked to an answer for "static class" ; but it is true it provides answer tp my question (second answer) ; but it is a quite tricky and date from 2011.
C# got new feature and maybe there is now a better solution to my question for "non static class". It is stated ; it is doable ; but not a prio to be added by C# peeps

I understand that extensions methods get first param this.
So static class can't get extension methods. stack overflow link
I don't think there is a way to add a static method outside the class.
One solution is to create an extension method and use the instance.
